# Python-Tkinter boolean-variable does not work

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *


def main():
  root = Tk()
  finish = Button(root, command=abcd)
  finish.grid(row=0, column=1)
  root.mainloop()


def abcd():
  global k1
  ku = Tk()
  k1 = BooleanVar()
  b = Button(ku, command=efgh)
  s = Checkbutton(ku, variable=k1)
  b.grid(row=1)
  s.grid(column=1)
  ku.mainloop()
  return


def efgh():
  global k1
  print(k1.get())
  return


main()
```

This is a shorter version of a project of mine. I want the code to print "true" when the checkbutton "s" is checked but instead it prints "false", no matter if it is checked or not. I created the two windows on purpose.
Where is the mistake?

Comment: The problem is that you're creating multiple `Tk` instances. Each program should have exactly one of those.

Comment: Yep, that works thanks!!